# Net Core 2.2 Web App - Cookie of browser too large on specific server

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, cookies

I have a web application running on .Net Core 2.2 and so far it has been deployed on various servers on IIS
[screenshot of web.config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nVUr.png)

The cookies created on all the servers so far are around 2.7kb

[screenshot of usual behavior - localhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ptlf.png)

[screenshot of usual behavior - public domain with htps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FltKX.png)

When deployed on a particular server that cookie becomes too large and is chunked. Causing problems overall [screenshot of chunked cookie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE4oP.png)

Does anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: Maybe in order to avoid having cookies with a dimension,  you can find answer in [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12192). You can read [ChunkingCookieManager Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.cookies.chunkingcookiemanager?view=aspnetcore-6.0) to know more.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into how I can modify my Claims mechanism but my main question is why on this particular deployment the cookies are so large. Does it have to do something with the configuration of the IIS?

On other servers it behaves like it should with a 2.7kb cookie.

Comment: I noticed something different between the two images. Domain and Secure. Does it mean that you are accessing the same site separately from the client and from the server itself? If so why is the value of secure different? So I think you should set the response header in IIS to cause the secure value of the two to be different. Can you show the web.config file applied in the second image?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have edited my question and added a screenshot of the web.config file, along with a screenshot from a public domain deployment which behaves as expected. (all 3 screenshots are from different websites. the localhost was simply me running it from visual studio)